# Вытаскивается неправильное название из JSON

Tags: php, json, vkontakte-api

Решил вытащить из вк название транслируемой музыки, но вытаскивается непонятно что.

```
<?php
$request = 'http://api.vkontakte.ru/method/users.get?uids=xenvert&fields=status';
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$info = json_decode($response, true);
var_dump($info);
foreach($info['response'] as $data){
    foreach ($data['status_audio'] as $song) {
        echo($song['artist']);
    }
}
?>
```

данный код выводит:

```
array(1) { 
    ["response"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(5) { 
            ["uid"]=> int(87581621) 
            ["first_name"]=> string(10) "РРіРѕСЂСЊ" 
            ["last_name"]=> string(10) "РЎР°Р»РёР№" 
            ["status_audio"]=> array(9) { 
                ["aid"]=> int(428001219) 
                ["owner_id"]=> int(87581621) 
                ["artist"]=> string(12) "Tim McIlrath" 
                ["title"]=> string(20) "What Are We Gonna Do" 
                ["duration"]=> int(243) 
                ["url"]=> string(155) "http://cs6093.vk.me/u12493734/audios/e096207ea781.mp3?extra=_6PaUdWEu_HsCr-UwAUdiay52ru8uK5tb-F227ZyutTKfD0zs_VSfyASSSZcgPzEYV_-qX83P73xANaDDtBEHVsMby8dtvE" 
                ["performer"]=> string(12) "Tim McIlrath" 
                ["lyrics_id"]=> string(8) "89253366" 
                ["album"]=> string(8) "68893982" 
            } 
            ["status"]=> string(0) "" 
        } 
    } 
} TWhT86
```

Где `TWhT86` - это название исполнителя, хотя написано что `["artist"]=> string(12) "Tim McIlrath"`
Через `print_r` название отображается правильно, но я не могу обратиться именно к `["artist"]`

Comment: спасибо @kff за форматтинг

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo($info['response'][0]['status_audio']['artist']); // Автор
echo($info['response'][0]['status_audio']['title']);  // Трек
```

Comment: похое на правду, мне только непонятно, что выводит этот скрипт :)))

Comment: Первая строка - __Автор__, вторая - __Название трека__

Comment: не ваш, а исходный :)

Comment: работает, спасибо!)

Comment: Насчет исходного - не могу предсказать так как Вы с работаете с Объектом как буд-то это массив. Пожалуйста.